# How to determine if view has translations and which ones

Tags: views, 8, i18n-l10n

I have a view

```
$view = \Drupal\views\Views::getView($view_id);
```

How to determine if it has been translated into other available languages and which ones

Answer (score 0):

I have been fighting with this lately, and can answer part of the question.  If you have the `$viewId` and `$displayId`, then the following seems to indicate whether a translation of the view label, title, and/or view menu entry exists in any language (but does not indicate the language):

```
$viewConfig = \Drupal::configFactory()->get("views.view.$viewId");
$hasTranslation = $viewConfig && ($viewConfig->hasOverrides('label') ||
  $viewConfig->hasOverrides("display.$displayId.display_options.menu.title") ||
  $viewConfig->hasOverrides('display.default.display_options.title'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we need to manually add path aliases for translated views, a set alias does provide an indirect opportunity to see if a translation exists.

You could check with `->lookupBySystemPath($path, $langcode)` to see if a view has a path alias for a given language.

```
// Set route match.
$routeMatch = \Drupal::routeMatch();

// Get route object.
$routeObject = $routeMatch->getRouteObject();

// Check if route object.
if ($routeObject) {

  // Get view id and display id from route.
  $view_id = $routeObject->getDefault('view_id');
  $display_id = $routeObject->getDefault('display_id');

  // Check if view.
  if (!empty($view_id) && !empty($display_id)) {

    // Get current path.
    $currentPath = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();

    // Get path alias repository.
    $pathAliasRepository = \Drupal::service('path_alias.repository');

    // Check if system path has Spanish alias.
    if ($pathAliasRepository->lookupBySystemPath($currentPath, 'es')) {

      // Do stuff...
    }
  }
}
```